# Add2Cart Magento Theme

Tags: magento, installation, themes

I have a Magento ecommerce created with "Add2Cart" (www.add2cart.com). I tried to install a new theme from ThemeForest bought but I had problems in the installation.
I followed step by step installation guide but apparently does not work. In the backend of magento are not at all or the name of the home page of the new theme or any new options related to the same topic. The version of Magento is 1.7.

- What could be the problem? What am I wrong?
- It's possible that this platform "Add2Cart" is not compatible with some particular topic?
- It's possible that there are restrictions on file permissions in ftp?

I've never had to do so I do not know !!

Here are the steps I follow the guide to install the new theme:

- Log out from Magento admin panel
- Using your FTP client (like FileZilla) go to your Magento root directory (it is the
  directory on your server where Magento is installed). Clear the store cache in
  var/cache directory (delete all the files inside). Do not delete var/cache folder! It's
  necessary since Magento uses cache heavily.
  Next, delete all cookies for your store domain in your web browser. All these steps
  will eliminate most of potential problems.
- Navigate inside Theme directory. Using your FTP client upload content of Theme
  directory to your Magento root directory.
- That's all. Now you can log in to Magento admin panel to enable and configure your
  new Magento theme.

If you can help I would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Did you assign the theme under System > Configuration > Design?

Comment: Yes, check the topic in System> Configuration> Design by inserting the name of the theme in "default", are just new colors in the frontend but the layout is that the various theme options in the backend are not! In that regard, I think that the files have been uploaded to the ftp in the right position otherwise it should not even change the css file. I just can not understand!

Comment: Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: Yes, I delete the cache first and then ftp off all entries from the backend;
The steps to follow are those listed above with the following

- When developing development your Magento store, you want to see the changes you have Implemented. In order to be Able to see changes, you need to disable caching system. To access the cache management screen go to System> Cache Management. Click Select All link, select Disable in the Actions field and click the Submit button;

Where am I wrong?